# Arduino, running a function simultaneously

Tags: c++, arduino

I am writing a printing function synonymous with 3D printing which reads an SD file and then acts on each line of the data. Below is my code: (variables have been assigned previously and code works).

```
void Print() {
  Home_Y();
  delay(100);
  Home_X();
  px = 75;
  py = 67.5;
  Read_SD(); //Opens the SD card
  while (printFile.available() > 0) {
    char character = printFile.read();
    if (bufferposition < buffer_size - 1)
    {
      Buffer[bufferposition++] = character;
    }
    if (character == '\n')
    {
      Buffer[bufferposition] = 0;
      //****************// add in command here
      bufferposition = 0;
    }
  }
  //The code then continues down further.
```

I want to run a separate function at the point in the code marked "//***//" continuously until switched off later in the code. My problem is that I can only run this function once, multiple calls would just delay the following processes.

**My Question:**

I was wondering if there was any way around this, or to simulate two functions running simultaneously. I have read somewhere about interrupts and timing delays, but wasn't sure if I was heading down the right path?

Comment: What you're looking for is called "coroutines", but afaik the current arduino compiler doesn't support that. Typically you write one of the two tasks asyncronously in the form of a method to be called over and over again (instead of a loop around it), and call that function inside of the loop of the other task (written with a classical loop). Or write both asyncronously and have a main loop outside of both, like a scheduler.

Comment: To complete what @leemes says, to accomplish this kind of thing on micro-controllor, most of time you need an specific OS like FreeRTOS, CMX, uCOS, .... which allow you to have many tasks running asyncronously